# Threadsafe moving arraylist elements among two arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency, thread-safety

Let's say I have two ArrayLists.

```
A1 = { 1, 2, 3}
A2 = { 4, 5}
```

I want to move element '4' to A1. I need a thread-safe solution to do that. For instance, the steps below may lose element '4' at a given time.

1. Remove element 4 from A2

*At this point, if another thread traverses the elements of those two arraylists, it will not see element 4.*

2. Insert element 4 to A1

I want this to be a whole process.

Comment: Do you already have some code for us?

Comment: synchronized or a lock, probably the easiest way

Comment: You first need to define what concurrent operations are possible. Is this "move" operation the only one that will be concurrent, or are there other operations going on in parallel on the lists as well?

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely read about [thread synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

The main idea: **Every** access to shared state (= the two lists) must be synchronized. In your case this can easily be done by using the `synchronized` keyword.

Example:

```
public class ThreadSafeObject<T> {
    private final List<T> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<T> a2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public synchronized void moveFromA1ToA2(int index) {
        T elem = a1.remove(index);
        a2.add(elem);
    }

    public synchronized void traverseA1(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
        a1.forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

As you can see, both methods are `synchronized`, which means that a thread must not enter any of the two methods if another thread is already executing any of these methods.

Note that it is **not** enough to just synchronize the move method. And you must not allow direct access to the two lists.

For more details about the `synchronized` keyword and intrinsic locks, read [the documentation mentioned above](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

**Addition**

Due to the discussion of this answer, I decided to add another solution using a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). The advantage of this solution is that threads do not lock each other when just traversing the list (= read access).

Note that the main principle is the same: We have to make **every** access to the lists thread safe! Even more, because we have an [*invariant*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Invariant_(computer_science)) that includes both lists, we have to use one and the same lock no matter if we want to access the first, the second or both lists.

Nevertheless, only accurate measurement can show if this solution is really faster in your concrete situation (using locks might be more expensive than `synchronized`).

```
public class ThreadSafeObject<T> {
    private final List<T> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<T> a2 = new ArrayList<>();

    private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(false);

    public void moveFromA1ToA2(int index) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            T elem = a1.remove(index);
            a2.add(elem);
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void traverseA1(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            a1.forEach(consumer);
        } finally {
            lock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: Any attempt to do a more sophisticated and more clever synchronization will probably fail. Lock striping might be a possible improvement, but therefore we must know more details about your requirements (e.g. does the order of the elements matter, can we have `null` items in-between, do you really want to traverse the lists in a certain order or is it sufficient to just search for items, etc.). Might not be worth the effort.*

Comment: At any time, any two threads can traverse the A1 :S I do not want to block A1's traverse as much as possible.

Comment: @isnot2bad but now you are just running away from the problem, you would need a constructor that takes these two lists as input and as such some other thread, outside that constructor can still alter the lists...

Comment: @Eugene But that would be the same with `synchronized`, anywhere you don´t aquire a lock on the lists you can still modify them. You would either have to use locks consistently or consistently use a wrapper class that does the locking for you, in the end it´s the same idea.

Comment: @ErayTuncer then, you would need a `ReadWriteLock`, but the main point remains: you have to make the entire application thread safe, i.e. control every access to the lists. You can not make a single operation thread safe in isolation.

Comment: @Holger I actually started coding such a thing, thinking that it would be fairly easy. But I've hit a certain unclarity oh how to expose that list outside a container. so for example I could have `private void moveElement(int index) {
            lock.writeLock().lock();
            try {
                left.add(right.remove(index));
            } finally {
                lock.writeLock().unlock();
            }
        }`

Comment: @Holger I thought about returning a copy of left, like `private List<T> getLeft() {
            lock.readLock().lock();

            try {
                return new ArrayList<>(left);
            } finally {
                lock.readLock().lock();
            }
        }` meaning that it is consistent with updates at the time when it is created. But now I am not sure if this would be something that the OP expects to be frank

Comment: @Eugene that doesn’t help you with the OP’s requirement that if someone invokes `getRight()` and `getLeft()`, the element should be in exactly one of these lists, in other words, anyone should perceive the move operation as atomic. You would need an object encapsulating both lists and cloning the entire compound object when making a snapshot, which is quiet an expensive thing, just for implementing the move of a single element…

Comment: @Holger wait, why wouldn't it be in one of the lists if `moveElement` is protected by the write lock? but otherwise in your last sentence are you implying that there could be an easier way?

Comment: @Eugene because the lock is meaningless if the caller doesn’t hold the lock while calling `getRight()` and `getLeft()`. Without holding the lock, it is still possible that the operation happens in-between these two calls. Then, depending on the order of these two calls, it’s possibile to see the moved element in neither or both of these lists. But with holding the lock, there is no advantage in making these copies, as the caller still needs to care about the lock.